# django-hvad: display just a few language tabs in admin when editing an object

Tags: django, django-hvad

With django-hvad extension, if I am editing a translatable object in admin I have dozens of languages displayed there. Is it possible to keep just two (czech and english) and remove all the rest?

Comment: What languages? How are you implementing multilingualism? Show some code.

Comment: Ok I thought your referring in view. I will research again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out it depends on variable [settings.LANGUAGES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-LANGUAGES). I solved it by defining the variable in settings.py:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('cs', 'Czech'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)
```